# Node JS bcrypt compare returns false

Tags: node.js, passport.js, bcrypt

So, I've seen a few posts about bcrypt compare returning false, but none seem to be a solution for me.

A quick explanation of what's what:

login handled with passport.
credentials stored in MySQL DB, using 'mysql' package.

These both seem to be working fine with plain text passwords.

The code of hashing and saving to the database:

```
    var newPlayer = (email,username,password,callback) =>{
        if(email && username &&password){
            bcrypt.hash(password, 16, function(err,hash){
                var sqlstr = sql.format("INSERT INTO players (email,username,password) VALUES (?,?,?);",[email,username, hash])
                console.log(sqlstr);
                connection.query(sqlstr,function(err, rows) {
                    if(err)console.log("[MYSQL] Error:",err);
                    if(callback)callback(err);
                })

            })

        } else {
            throw Error("[MYSQL]  New Player requires email, username and password");
        }

    }
```

and the code for comparing (snippet from passport config):

```
        DAO.getPlayer(email,function(player){
            if(player)
            bcrypt.compare(password,player.password,(err,match)=>{
                if(err){
                    console.log("[PASSPORT] BCRYPT ERR:",err)
                    done(null,false)
                }
                else if(match)
                return done(null,player)
                else
                return done(null, false)
            })
            else
            return done(null, false)
        })
```

Thanks in advance for any help, and if I need to specify something, let me know! :)

Comment: What data type are you using in your database to store the password?

Comment: It's a varchar - length 45

Comment: The hash that bcrypt generates will be of `60` character. Try increasing the size of the column. [https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js#hash-info](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js#hash-info)

Comment: How did I miss this! Thanks a lot, working fine now.

Comment: @SeraphimJester Glad that worked! Now, answering the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash that `bcrypt` generates will be of 60 character. Try increasing the size of the column.

> Hash Info
>
> The characters that comprise the resultant hash are ./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789$.
>
> Resultant hashes will be 60 characters long.

https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js#hash-info